functional definition of tuples (Terrence Tao Analysis, execise 3.5.2)
I came across this particular exercise in T. Tao Analysis book:
Suppose we define an ordered $n$-tuple to be a surjective function $x : \{i ∈ N : 1 ≤ i \leq n\} \to X$ whose range is some arbitrary set $X$ (so different ordered $n$-tuples are allowed to have different ranges); we then write $x_i$ for $x(i)$, and also write $x$ as $(x_{i})_{1≤i≤n}$. Using this definition, verify that we have $(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} = (y_i)_{1≤i≤n}$ if and only if $x_{i} = y_{i}$ for all $1 ≤ i ≤ n$. Also, show that if $(X_i)_{1≤i≤n}$ are an ordered $n$-tuple of sets, then the Cartesian product, as defined in Definition 3.4.3 (Ordered n-tuple and n-fold Cartesian product), is indeed a set. (Hint: use Exercise 3.4.7 and the axiom of specification.
I started proving the first statement without looking at the hint and this was my attempt:
First, we verify that $(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} = (y_i)_{1≤i≤n}$ if and only if $x_{i} = y_{i}$ for all $1 ≤ i ≤ n$.

we show that $(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} = (y_i)_{1≤i≤n}\implies$$x_{i} = y_{i}$ for all $1 ≤ i ≤ n$.

Suppose $(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} = (y_i)_{1≤i≤n}$.
Let $y$ and $x$ be any two surjective functions $x:\{ 1,2,\dots,n \}\to X$ and $y:\{ 1,2,\dots,n \}\to Y$.
Thus, $(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} = (y_i)_{1≤i≤n}$ means that $x=y$, so for each index $i\in \{ 1,2,\dots n \}$ the corresponding elements in the tuples, namely, $x(i)$ and $y(i)$ are equal.
Thus, by definition, $x_i=y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

we show that $x_{i} = y_{i}$ for all $1 ≤ i ≤ n\implies$ $(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} = (y_i)_{1≤i≤n}$.

If $x_i=y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, we have that $x(i)=y(i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.
Since the domains of $x$ and $y$ are the same and for every $i$ in the domain we have $x(i)=y(i)$, we need only show that $X=Y$ to conclude that $x=y$.
Let $a\in X$. Since $x$ is surjective, there exists $i\in \{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$ such that $a=x(i)$. Since $x(i)=y(i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, we have that $a\in Y$. Thus, $X\subseteq Y$.
Similarly for $b\in Y$, since $y$ is surjective there exists $i\in \{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$ such that $b=y(i)$. Since $y(i)=x(i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, we have that $b\in X$. Thus $Y\subseteq X$.
Since $Y\subseteq X$ and $X\subseteq Y$, it follows that $X=Y$.
Thus, we have that the domain and ranges of $x$ and $y$ are the same, and for every $i$ in the domain, $x(i)=y(i)$. By definition of equality for functions, $x=y$. Thus, by the defition provided by the exercise, $(x_i)_{1≤i≤n} = (y_i)_{1≤i≤n}$.
After finishing the first part of the proof, I realized there was a hint and that I never used any of the hinted propositions, so my question are:

Are the hints strictly used in proving the second part of the exercise?
If the hint was intended for the first part, is my proof at all correct (since I never used the hints, I think there is a high chance that I assumed something that I could not)
Also, my first instinct was to use induction on $n$, but after several attempts at this, I gave up. Should I have kept in this line of reasoning?


I find it weird that Tao uses the term "range" rather than co-domain or some other term. Is Tao really using "range" to mean co-domain. or is $x$ as a function really supposed to be onto?

@ThomasAndrews That puzzled me too. Perhaps what is meant is that the range is a subset of $X$ and that the function is surjective onto its range. That might not be always true, depending on Tau's definition of "range". Tao is really careful about these kinds of fundamentals, so the confusion is probably the OP's transcription.

@EthanBolker, the transcription of this question is correct. Tao used the term range in the exercise. In spite of this, everything in my attempt should be taken with a grain of salt, since I`m new to this, and self teaching the subject.

@IgorMello OK. Then I think "surjective" and "range = $X$" say the same thing. That's just a little redundancy and does not affect the meaning of the question. Your proof of the first assertion  looks correct on quick reading - it's essentially the definition of a function. I think the hint is for the second part, proving that the cartesion product of sets is in fact a set.

Let me first discuss Tao's terminology. Recalling Definition 3.3.1, in a function $f : X \to Y$ the set $X$ is called its domain and the set $Y$ its range. Many other authors prefer to say codomain instead of range, but notation is not standardized. See here. He also uses the phrase image for what the "codomain-supporters" usually denote as range.
When Tao defines $n$-tuples as functions $x : [n] = \{1,\ldots,n\} \to X$ it is essential that $x$ is required to be surjective because he wants that the range $X$ is uniquely determined by the values $x_1,\ldots, x_n$, i.e. that $X = f([n]) = \{f(i) \mid i \in [n] \} = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ in the sense of his informal Definition 3.1.1. Without surjectivity we could only say that $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \subset X$.
Your proof of the first part is correct. It is obvious that $x = y$ implies that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i \in [n]$, and this part works without surjectivity. Surjectivity is needed to show that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i \in [n]$ implies $x = y$.
The hint only concerns the second part. Actually Tao gave a proof in Remark 3.5.8, and you can formalize it using Exercise 3.5.2. Note that Exercise 3.5.2 is already referenced in Definition 3.5.7 (Ordered n-tuple and n-fold Cartesian product).
